# GMail keeps logging into the wrong account,how do I remove one from the list?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

My daughter logged into gmail on my machine running Chrome, and now every time I open gmail to it goes to her account.

I can switch to mine using the "user menu" on the right, but this leaves the other window open, and I don't want to have to do it anyway.

So is there a way to remove an account from the "user menu"? I can't see any option for this anywhere.

Comment: After you click Sign Out, and you have clicked Sign In on the main Google page, there will be a Remove button at the bottom of the page.  You should press that button to remove the account from the lists of Google accounts you can select.  If this question is moved to the proper SE website I will go ahead an answer it there (provided it's not a duplicate).  If you are talking about, Chrome is logged into the other Google account, just delete the user profile directory, for that user in question (you can also just log out of the account)

Comment: @Ramhound - worked like a champ. If you make that an answer I'll upvote it!

Comment: The question needs to be migrated before I can do that.